# In Google reCaptcha, why two different key used e.g. Private Key and Public Key - What is the specific purpose for both keys?

Tags: recaptcha

In Google reCaptcha, why two different key used e.g. Private Key and Public Key 
**My question is -  What is the specific purpose for each keys ?**

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a relatively old question, but in the hope that it can still help you or someone else in the future..

Recapcha uses the standard [public/private key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) cryptography implementation. To quote the link (Wikipedia)

> ..two separate keys, one of which is secret (or private) and one of
>   which is public. Although different, the two parts of this key pair
>   are mathematically linked. The public key is used to encrypt plaintext
>   or to verify a digital signature; whereas the private key is used to
>   decrypt ciphertext or to create a digital signature.